# Bootstrap tooltip showing on second mouse enter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

So I have a generic selecter like this in my javascript.js file:

```
$(document).on('hover', '*[rel=tooltip]', function(e){
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

And throughout my HTML files I have tags that may have `rel='tooltip'` ie:

```
<i class="icon-ban-circle" rel="tooltip" title="Ban" data-placement="bottom"></i>
<a rel="tooltip" title="hover for tooltip">Text</a>
```

This solution works, but with a caveat. You have to hover over the element a second time for the tooltip to show. I like the fact that I can just add a `rel="tooltip"` and `title="some text"` to my HTML and have the tooltips show up right away and want to keep that convenience.

I've created a JSFiddle demoing this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xKKMM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on({
    'mouseenter': function (e) {
        $(this).tooltip('show');
    },
        'mouseeleave': function (e) {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    }
}, '*[rel=tooltip]');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCRw8/)**

What happens in your case is only during the first hover it sets up the tooltip by calling tooltip constructor. And then onwards when you hover it is already set up so it shows when hovered. You can combine the setup with this. But this will invoke the constructor on every hover. So you can avoid it by just doing it at once like this.

```
$('*[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but on mouseout there seems to be some blinking. Should I change hover to mouseenter and mouseleave?

Comment: @Xecure i.e because of document.hover, remove it and bind it to the selector as my second example.